# how to move the text be next to the image

Tags: html, css

You have built a HTML page as well as an artcle but it appears here in the image minus space between the image and the text

I want the text to be next to the image so that its shape is distinctive

html :

```css
/* Start content Article .. */

.contentmqal {
    width: 80%;
    float: left;
}

article {
    margin: 15px;
    background: #f7e9e3;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 8px;
}

article section {
    float: right;
    clear: left
}

article section p {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
            <div class="contentmqal">
            <!-- Start Content Article -->
            <article>
                <section>
                    <h3>One Year ago: Durian Fruit</h3>
                    <p>The durian is a tropical fruit. It is from Malaysia. People know it for its sharp smell. Some people say... <span>read more</span></p>
                </section>
                <img src="image/a1.jpg" alt="Durain Fruit" title="One Year ago: Durian Fruit" width="238px" />
            </article>
            </div>
<!-- End Content Artcle -->
```

http://prntscr.com/lo22wh

i want the text in red box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `flex` to the container.

Try this. Also use align-items:center if you want them to be centered

Also set `order:2` to the `section` so that it will float to the right side

Try this

```css
/* Start content Article .. */

.contentmqal {
    width: 80%;
    float: left;
}

article {
    margin: 15px;
    background: #f7e9e3;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 8px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

article section {
    float: right;
    clear: left;
    order: 2;
}

article section p {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
            <div class="contentmqal">
            <!-- Start Content Article -->
            <article>
                <section>
                    <h3>One Year ago: Durian Fruit</h3>
                    <p>The durian is a tropical fruit. It is from Malaysia. People know it for its sharp smell. Some people say... <span>read more</span></p>
                </section>
<img src="image/a1.jpg" alt="Durain Fruit" title="One Year ago: Durian Fruit" width="238px" />
            </article>
            </div>
<!-- End Content Artcle -->
```

Comment: I'm glad you find it useful, have a nice day. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `display:flex` to `article`

```css
.contentmqal {
    width: 80%;
    float: left;
}

article {
display:flex;
    margin: 15px;
    background: #f7e9e3;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 8px;
}

article section {
    float: right;
    clear: left
}

article section p {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="contentmqal">
 <article>
 <img src="image/a1.jpg" alt="Durain Fruit" title="One Year ago: Durian Fruit" width="238px" />
 <section>
  <h3>One Year ago: Durian Fruit</h3>
  <p>The durian is a tropical fruit. It is from Malaysia. People know it for its sharp smell. Some people say... <span>read more</span></p>
</section>

 </article>
</div>
```

Comment: But I appeared in an anarchic and irregular way
http://prntscr.com/lo29ul

Comment: set the `img` before article in html

Comment: @לבנימלכה no need to change the content here. We have to use `order:2` to float the section to the right